# pushing ViewController over current ViewController from deeplink swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using deeplink in my application and from the central area, I am trying push a screen in another ViewController based on my deeplink.

The issues I have is that when I cancel the pushed ViewController, the entire application stack is dismissed and I just want to pop back to the presenting viewcontroler.

```
func getCurrentNanvigationController() -> UINavigationController? {
        
        //targeted UINavigationController 
        var navigationController: UINavigationController? = nil
        
        if let nav = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            
            if let topNav = window?.topViewController()?.navigationController {
                navigationController = topNav
            }
            else{
                navigationController = nav
            }
        }
        
        // Wallet Module is the stand alone module, which means its not embeded in the Navigator app
        else if let tabBar = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
                let nav  = tabBar.selectedViewController as?  UINavigationController {
            navigationController = nav
        }
        
        else {
            //should not happen, window root controller shouldbe be either UINavigationController or UITabBarController
        }
        return navigationController
        
    }

public extension UIWindow {
    func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        var top = self.rootViewController
        while true {
            if let presented = top?.presentedViewController {
                top = presented
            } else if let nav = top as? UINavigationController {
                top = nav.visibleViewController
            } else if let tab = top as? UITabBarController {
                top = tab.selectedViewController
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return top
    }
}
```

This is the currentViewController that I am trying to push another controller over from the deeplink

```
@objc func addNavBarItemTapped() {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .addVC, bundle: .main)
        let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController")

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
```

How can I effectively push over the `AddViewController` because that is the presenting ViewController and when I dismiss the presented ViewController from the navigation stack, I am not removing the entire app navigation but instead returning back to `AddViewController`

How the dismissal of this view controller is achieved is like this.

```
public extension UIViewController {
    
    func alert(title: String,
               message: String? = nil  ,
               attributedMessage: NSMutableAttributedString? = nil,
               okAction: AlertActionButton = ("ok_button".fpxLocalizedText, .default, nil),
               cancelAction: AlertActionButton = (nil, .cancel, nil),
               complete: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        if let attributedMessage = attributedMessage {
            alertController.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")
        }
        let oKAction = UIAlertAction(title: okAction.0, style: okAction.1, handler: okAction.2)
        if let cancelButtonTitle = cancelAction.0 {
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: cancelAction.1, handler: cancelAction.2)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        }
        alertController.addAction(oKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: complete)
    }
}
```

In the presented Viewcontroller

```
public func declineButtonClicked() {
        alert(title: "decline_warning_title".fpxLocalizedText,
              message: "decline_warning_message".fpxLocalizedText,
              okAction: ("yes_button".fpxLocalizedText, .destructive, { _ in self.sendDeclineRequest() }),
              cancelAction: ("decline_cancel_button".fpxLocalizedText, .cancel, { _ in self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }))
    }
```

Also sometimes if I have a presented Viewcontroller and need to show this ViewController, it is often presented in the background of the presented viewcontroller

Comment: Where is the part of the code where you "dismiss" or "cancel" the presented view controller? Isn't that what the question is about?

Comment: @matt I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In iOs push duty perform with UINavigationController
wherever you need to push so you need to UINavigationController.

You should Create another UInavigationController in Deep Link,

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .addVC, bundle: .main)
let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController")
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:controller)

self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or

```
window?.getCurrentNanvigationController().present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

so now you have a new navigation controller that work stand alone.